# Peer to Peer UDP Sockets in Golang

Tags: go, sockets, networking, udp

I have a distributed application which sends messages among a number of peers. I've been switching over from TCP to UDP. I've seen that UDP can send and receive using a single socket so I've attempted to implement the application with each server containing a single socket.

I've set up a little piece of code to test this out but it returns `EHOSTUNREACH (65)` when attempting to invoke `WriteToUDP` on `UDPC`

```
Id // assumed to be a unique for the server
PeerAddrList // assumed to be a slice of all server locations (addr:port strings)
N // assumed to be the number of servers

laddr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", PeerAddrList[Id])
UDPC, er := net.ListenUDP("udp", laddr)
if er != nil {
    panic(er)
}

for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
    if i == int(Id) {
        continue
    }
    i := i
    go func() {
        var b [4]byte
        bs := b[:4]
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bs, uint32(Id))
        radddr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", PeerAddrList[i])
        if _, er := UDPC.WriteToUDP(bs, radddr); er != nil { 
            panic(er)
        }
    }()
}

for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
    if i == int(Id) {
        continue
    }
    var b [4]byte
    bs := b[:4]
    _, raddr, e := UDPC.ReadFromUDP(bs)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    // check if laddr == id
    id := int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bs))
    log.Printf("Got id %d from %s", id, raddr.String())
}
```

Any advice on why this behaviour is different from what I expected, or how to fix it, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the reason why the problem existed is that I was testing on my loopback address but didn't specify the address in PeerAddrList, only ":PORT". When giving addresses as "127.0.0.1:PORT" SendTo on the UDP socket worked